# BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, backup, logging

`BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE ... WITH DIFFERENTIAL. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.`

I see this message in SQL Server log file viewer. Where is the backup application log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. It was caused by a Windows Backup on Windows Server 2008, which was also doing a full backup (behind the scene). And this caused that the SQL Server diff backup was unable to find the last full backup.

We solved the problem by migration to Windows Server 2008 **R2**.

Answer (score 4):

To get detailed information about the problem:

1. Go to SQL Server Management Studio -> SQL Server Agent -> Jobs
2. Right click the name of the job which causes troubles and select "View History"
3. In Log File Viewer window, select error end view detailed error message.

In my case, the problem was in the next error:

> error: "BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Web Edition (64-bit).  BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Answer (score 2):

I think this means the Application Event Log on the Server.

Are using a TSQL script to execute this backup job via SQLAgent?  If so, you need to specify an Output file on the job step that contains the BACKUP TSQL.

In the Job Step on the left hand pane there should be `General` & `Advanced`.  Click on `Advanced` and under title **Transact-SQL script (T-SQL)** there is an output file box.  Enter any valid filename here (it doesn't need to exist, it will create it on the fly).

Once you have done this re-run your job and further detailed error messages will be written to this file.

UPDATE:

Have you previously performed a `FULL` database backup for this database?  A `FULL` backup needs to exist before a `DIFFERENTIAL` backup can be performed.

Comment: This same message is in the Application Event Log.

Comment: I am using `Back Up Database Task`.

Comment: yes I have following schedule: each Sunday full backup, each day except Sunday diff backup. Full backups are backuping ok, but diff are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows event logs (Application Log).  Start->Run eventvwr